Opamp Constant Current Driver Weird Behavior
I put together this circuit for driving a laser diode channel with a forward voltage of 16V at 3A. I have made this circuit before, tested and made PCB's that all work perfectly. The ones I made previously had a slightly more complex reference voltage network with two pots for adjustable current and offset current, but it is virtually the same as it still is sending a certain reference voltage to the non-inverting input. For whatever reason this time, whenever I disconnect the switch, the op-amp output still drives 1.7V to the gate, which is enough for the laser diodes to turn on dimly, below the lazing threshold. It is barely enough current to read more than 0.1mV over the shunt resistor. I never had this problem before and I can't figure out why it is happening. Testing my other circuits that are working the op-amp drives only 5mV or so to the gate when the switch is open. I thought that maybe I used a damaged MOSFET or op-amp, but replacing both gives the same result. I've been trying to troubleshoot this to no end. I know I could just use an LM388 constant current circuit for this, but I need to know whats going on here. The circuit below is what exhibits the weird behavior, and the second picture is the circuit for the working drivers I already have. 

Did you check with the scope whether current doesn’t oscillate?

Try giving that 358 a smal negative rail and see if it changes anything.

Use the input bias currents to get the op amp output voltage down. With switch SW1 open the noninverting input sees 8.2k (R5) while the inverting input sees ~1k (R3). Raise the value of R3 (try R3 >> R5) until the op amp output voltage is close(r) to 0V.

0.1mV across current-sense is well within the offset voltage spec of a LM358. Maybe you need a lower-offset opamp, or add an offset trimpot.

@Michal Podmanický I have checked and there is no oscillation.

@Burglups using the switch to clamp the output to gnd instead of the current setup will damage the laser diodes. Since when the switch is closed the opamp will be driving its output as high as it can, and when I open it there will be a short current spike through the laser diodes, at least that's what I understand. The capacitor c7 is a soft start mechanism for the current through the laser diodes.

@glen_geek I see that, however I'm not sure why I have 5 of the working circuits that work perfectly and don't exhibit this behavior. They use the same MOSFET and op-amp.

OK - that's reasonable. Then I'd investigate where ground currents flow. Your 0.1 ohm current sense resistor gives you such small feedback voltage that ground currents flowing along copper traces become significant. For example, try connecting the +18V ground return to other points along the ground track. R5's GND should be coincident with R2's GND (in your new circuit).
